In onlyoffice, how do the callbackUrl is used every time when I save the file?
In onlyoffice, how do the callbackUrl is used every time when I save the file?
I try do this but it didn't work.
I've tried a lot of things, but still haven't solved the problem.
I hope someone can answer that question. Thank you so much.
enter image description here
